# How avoid code duplication in visitor and const visitor base classes

Tags: c++, software-design, code-duplication

I have 2 classes `ConstVisitorBase` and `VisitorBase` which contain some code to visit objects. for example:

```cpp
struct Node
{
    enum class Type { ... };
    Type type;
}

class ConstVisitorBase
{
    public:
        virtual void VisitType1( Node const & node );
        ...

    private:
        void VisitNode( Node const & node )
        {
            switch( node.type )
            {
                case Node::Type::type1: VisitType1( node );
            }
            ...
        }
}

class VisitorBase
{
    public:
        virtual void VisitType1( Node & node );
        ...

    private:
        void VisitNode( Node & node )
        {
            switch( node.type )
            {
                case Node::Type::type1: VisitType1( node );
            }
            ...
        }
}
```

The code for the private method `VisitNode` is identical other than the `const` specifier.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication?
Even when there are multiple methods involved ( `VisitNode` calling `EnterNode` and `LeaveNode` )?

Comment: Why do you need to implement a separate class to visit const node?

Comment: const visitors can run in parallel on the same data structure *, whilst a normal ( modifying ) visitor **needs** to be run sequentially. And in other cases you might not want your data structure to be modified but still allow reading.


( * can often be made to allow parallel reads )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `VisitType1` are public and the two classes are unrelated, you can use a template function:

```
template<typename Visitor, typename T>
void dispatch_visits(Visitor& visitor, T&& node){
    switch( node.type )
    {
        case Node::Type::type1: visitor.VisitType1( node );
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still require two `dispatch_visits` methods, one with `Node const &` and one with `Node &` both with identical implementation?

Comment: @SamCoutteau Ups, missed that, well we can make it more general then and use `T&&` which can deduce const.